Packaging jar + JRE with Launch4J
I'm trying to create a Windows executable from my Java app (app.jar). I'm using Launch4J to do this
I created a folder called appfolder, which contains the app.jar and a folder called jre (which contains the bin & lib of a Windows JRE). I used Launch4J to create the executable, outputting to appfolder, ensuring that the JRE path is set to "jre" (as the java runtime path needs to be relative to the jar file).
I opened up the appfolder folder in a Windows VM, and tried to run the exe. It would just open and then close immediately.
I've tried putting JRE for different computer architecture into the jre folder, and when I run the exe, it comes up with an error along the lines of "java runtime needed", so it seems like the jre is not the issue??
I've also tried to run the exe from cmd (enabling launch4j debug flag), no output there also. Not 100% sure this actually does what I need it to?
It'd be nice if there are logs or something that I can look at when the application is opened, so I can see what's happening to make it close immediately.
Any suggestions? Thank you!

I don't know Launch4J, but just to say, you don't need 3rd party tools
